# How Do I make my Setup Project Include my Database (.sdf) file along with the winform application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have created a Winforms application in VS 10 (C#), with SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 as a back end.

First I created a new setup project by following [these](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-create-an-installer-for-a-winform-application-using-s/) steps.

But I got **database file could not be found** exception on installing application on client's machine.

Then I tried creating a setup project and included my database (.sdf) file in **Application Folder** and I got following exception:

> Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region.

I am getting the database file by following code :

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("DataSource=|DataDirectory|\\myDatabase.sdf");
```

And my `DataDirectory` is pointing to the `path`

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
```

Can anyone please help me including my database file?

Comment: Program Files folder is not writeable, and this is probably why you have issue. Watch out for a new blog post on my blog being published this monday.

Comment: Under which folder .sdf resides when you run the program from Visual Studio ? How do you refer basically ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the database file to your applications folder in your setup.

Then in your connection use

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("DataSource=myDatabase.sdf");
```